# Login form does not work, keeps loading again after submitting in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am making a blog application in Symfony2 and I wanted to make a login form.
What I did so far:

1. connected my User Entity with Security
2. made a form
3. configured routes and security.yml.

And it just doesn't want to work. When I try to submit username and password all I get is a login form again. I think it is a problem with routes, but I can't figure this out. Could anyone point me where are any errors here?

SecurityController:

```
<?php

namespace BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class SecurityController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction()
{
    $authUtil = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // error content
    $error = $authUtil->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authUtil->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('BlogBundle:Default:login.html.twig', array(
            'error' => $error,
            'last_username' => $lastUsername)
    );
}

}
```

security.yml:

```
security:

providers:
    db_provider:
        entity:
            class: BlogBundle:Users
            property: username

firewalls:

    main:
       anonymous: ~
       form_login:
            provider: db_provider
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
```

Login form:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="_username" type="text" autofocus>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="_password" type="password" value="">
</div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
```

Comment: I think you have a problem with your routes configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright, so I seem to have found the solution.
You see, when you're reading tutorial for making a form in Symfony 2 it tells you to make the same route for login_path and check_path.
http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

What I failed to realize was that this route is associated with loginAction in SecurityController, so whenever I was trying to submit the form it was going back to loginAction where I was rendering login page.

The solution was to make another method in SecurityController:

```
 /**
 * @Route("login_check", name="login_check")
 */
public function loginCheck(){

}
```

I left it empty, but you can put there some exception handler if you want, like:

```
throw new \Exception("Oops")
```

And of course I changed form post action and check_path in security.yml to *login_check* also

Answer (score 2):

You should take a loook at login page security config:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html#be-sure-the-login-page-isn-t-secure-redirect-loop

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel when there is already a bundle that does that. Check out FOSUserBundle. It is a great bundle that provides a flexible security framework and allows you to load users from configuration or databases. 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html
Hope it helps!

Comment: I know there is but I just wanted to make it for the studying purpose and abandoning it just didn't seem right.